# dynamic name react component not created

Tags: reactjs

I've read topics and tutorials but I don't know what's wrong with my dynamic names:

I tried in 3 different way. Only the 1st one is working.

I am in a .js file:

```
render() {
    let componentList = {
        Delete: 'DeleteIcon',
    };
    let ComponentName = "Delete";
    let ChildComponent = componentList[ComponentName];


    let test = (CompName, props) => {
        return React.createElement(CompName, props);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <DeleteIcon color="#71f1aa" />
            <ChildComponent color="#71f1aa" />
            {test('DeleteIcon', {color: "#71f1aa"})}
        </div>
    );
}
```

`<DeleteIcon color="#71f1aa" />` is one of my component and it is displaying well,

`<ChildComponent color="#71f1aa" />` will be created but will be empty,

`{test(ChildComponent, {color: "#71f1aa"})}` will be created but will be empty too.

In the second and third case, it'll be on props read-only and it won't display my component.

this is my DeleteIcon:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

type DeleteIconProps = {
    className?: ?string,
    color?: string
};

export default class DeleteIcon extends Component<DeleteIconProps> {
    static defaultProps = {
        color: "#40B474"
    };

    render() {
        const {color, className} = this.props;
        return (
            <svg viewBox="0 0 59 59" className={className} height={24} width={24}>
                <defs>
                    <clipPath id="a">
                        <path d="M0 0h59v59H0z"/>
                    </clipPath>
                </defs>
                <g clip-path="url(#a)">
                    <path d="M52.5 6H38.456c-.11-1.25-.495-3.358-1.813-4.711C35.809.434 34.751 0 33.499 0H23.5c-1.252 0-2.31.434-3.144 1.289C19.038 2.642 18.653 4.75 18.543 6H6.5a1 1 0 1 0 0 2h2.041l1.915 46.021C10.493 55.743 11.565 59 15.364 59h28.272c3.799 0 4.871-3.257 4.907-4.958L50.459 8H52.5a1 1 0 1 0 0-2zm-32 44a1 1 0 1 1-2 0V17a1 1 0 1 1 2 0v33zm10 0a1 1 0 1 1-2 0V17a1 1 0 1 1 2 0v33zm10 0a1 1 0 1 1-2 0V17a1 1 0 1 1 2 0v33zM21.792 2.681C22.24 2.223 22.799 2 23.5 2h9.999c.701 0 1.26.223 1.708.681.805.823 1.128 2.271 1.24 3.319H20.553c.112-1.048.435-2.496 1.239-3.319z" fill={color}/>
                </g>
            </svg>
        )
    }
}
```

What should I do ?
Ty for your help !

Comment: What happens if you remove the quotes from `componentList`? - ex: from `Delete: 'DeleteIcon',` to `Delete: DeleteIcon,`

Comment: TY that solved the problem !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in `componentList`

```
let componentList = {
    Delete: 'DeleteIcon',
};
```

`componentList.Delete` is a string, not a component.
Changing `componentList` to

```
let componentList = {
    Delete: DeleteIcon
};
```

fixes the problem.